# Why is my list being passed like a reference when I did not tell it to be passed by reference?

Tags: c#, list, parameters

I have created a method where a pass a list to it. Here is what the method looks like:

```
private  bool ShouldEnable(int Index, List<LabelDisplay> ListOfLabels)
{
        LabelDisplay LabelToTest = ListOfLabels[Index];
        ...
}
```

The LabelDisplay class is a class I have created in the program. So when I pass the list of LabelDisplay classes,

```
if(ShouldEnable(i,Labels))
    Labels[i].Enable = true;
```

It should pass it as a value and not by reference. However, when debugging, I notice that if I remove an item from ListOfLabels in the ShouldEnable() method it will also remove it from Labels. My current work around is this:

```
List<LabelDisplay> LabelList = new List<LabelDisplay>();
foreach(LabelDisplay LabelDis in ListOfLabels)
{
    LabelList.Add(LabelDis);
}
```

But this is very slow and I am looking for something faster.

Note that:

```
List<LabelDisplay> LabelList = ListOfLabels;
```

The above line doesn't work as for some reason if I remove an Item from LabelList, it will still effect the Labels list(List that I passed to the Method). This seems like a very odd problem. So how do I make it so that I can remove and mess around with this list as much as I want but it will still not effect the original list that I passed to it?

Comment: List<LabelDisplay> LabelList = ListOfLabels;The reason it's not working is that you are making a reference to LabelList via ListOfLabels.i.e both of them point the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually passing by value in this case, it's just that the value of a reference-type variable, is a reference to an object. However you are still passing by value - the value of the incoming parameter copied to ListOfLabels, but that value is a reference to your List, so yes, they will still point to the same list, not a copy of it.

Try here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s6938f28.aspx

If you want to make a copy of your list, a quick way to do so is to simply pass it into the constructor of a new list.

e.g.:

```
List<LabelDisplay> copyOfList = new List<LabelDisplay>(OriginalList);
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really illuminate the OP's problem.  In general discussions, we usually say "pass by reference" anyway, and even those of us who know that it really means "pass reference by value" still understand what someone means when they say "pass by reference."

Comment: @RobertHarvey You cannot just shorten, "pass a reference by value" to "pass by reference" because passing something by reference, *already has a meaning, and it means a radically different thing*.  If there was no other semantic meaning of "pass by reference" other than meaning to "pass a reference by value" then it's not so dangerous.  In Java for example you can never ever pass anything by reference, so there is no behavior to confuse it with.  In C# you can actually passing things by reference, and the two behaviors behave differently, so you simply can't conflate them.

Comment: @Servy [Tell that to Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.120).aspx).  Java is a non-factor here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Microsoft is *using the term correctly* to refer to what it means to *actually* pass something by reference.  You're using the same term to refer to some thing with *radically different semantics*, which is wrong.  The term itself is not universally wrong.  There is actually such a thing as passing a parameter by reference, this just isn't doing that.

Comment: The link you've posted explains the difference between value and reference variables types and, if you click through to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx, it explains exactly what passing by value and passing by reference mean in C#. It doesn't conflate passing a reference by value and actually passing by reference, as you are doing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an easy way to make a copy of the list, since I think that's what the OP really needs here.